# How to record my voice and output to speaker at the same time?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, headphones, speakers, recording

When giving a speech, I want to record my voice and let people in the room hear clearly through a speaker. I have a macbook air, a bluetooth headset and a bluetooth speaker. Thanks.

Comment: That is your only equipment?  How large is the audience?  Is the facility equipped with sound equipment?  The microphone should be able to pick up all sound while the speakers output, just a matter of feedback.

Comment: Thanks. This is my only equipment. Do I need something else? This is a room without any sound equipment. The groups size is about 30. I just want to pick up the speaker's voice, not the sound in the room.

Comment: I see.  Have you tried a dry run?

Comment: I did. Failed. I could not do both: recording & output by a speaker.

Answer (score 1):

You need a USB Audio Mixer like this one [Presonus Audiobox USB](http://amzn.to/1O2vbCk)

When you use audio software, if you CAN monitor the output, there will be a delay because it has to come in through the mic, record to disk, they play it back.

What this device does is take the live audio and send it into two different directions:

- to your computer for recording
- to an external device like a PA system or audio system

When you use this, you are not depending on your computer to play it back - it will go directly to the PA system while simultaneously recording it.

The best part is you can adjust the levels for your PA and recording independently so the quality is good on both - not on one and horrible on the other.

Using the Presonus as an example:

[image: Presonus Front]
[image: Presonus Back]

Your mic would go into 1 on the front and you would have your computer plugged into the USB (back) and the MAIN OUT (back) would go to the PA.  You just need the right plugs at this point.

I have used this setup many times and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark here, but I am assuming your issue may be that the audio you are inputting is not being replayed as system audio out. I believe you can get garageband to both record and "monitor" (or play your audio back for you through the speakers) at the same time.

I just tried and could not get garageband to pick up my mic in my bluetooth headset, so I am not sure if this will help, but at least it might get the next commenter started.